# Network Card Recognition Issues

Tags: networking

I use Ubuntu on my laptop Lenovo and 2 desktop Asus+HP. My main desktop is HP Prodesk 400 G3 Pentium dual-core at 3,2Ghz and 8 Gb ram. It runs very well W11 because he has all requirements from Microsoft. I`ve installed it with clean and original Iso from Microsoft. But I would rather use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS instead of Windows 11. I don't want to dual-boot! The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't recognize the ethernet network card, I only have access to the net through wireless pen-usb with much slower speeds. Is it a problem with the configuration of the bios, of drivers? Of the security requirements? I feel frustrated! I would like to upgrade processor and ram but only if I can access the network by network card and not usb stick. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: We need to know what kind of Ethernet card your computer has. Open a terminal and enter the command: `lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %` Then copy the output of the command and paste it [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506859/edit). Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit windows. Also add the output of this command: `uname -r`,

Comment: My HP Prodesk has W11 now, not Linux. Ethernet Card is Realtek RTL8111HSH-CG GbE. It don`t recognized Ethernet IP adress almost times. If I desconnect wired cable sometimes it connects but soon the communication will be loosed. Sorry my English, I`m not using translator. Many tks!

Comment: If I desconnect and connected it again, I mean!